# Convert NTFS TO FAT file system

Tags: files, system, convert

How I change NTFS file system to FAT or MS-DOS file system without losing my data using Linux Commands?

Comment: You must **back up** all the data on the NTFS file system before you reformat it to avoid losing everything that is stored on the NTFS partition. A good way of backing up the data on the NTFS file system is to back it up to an external hard drive.

Comment: Marking either of the answer as 'Accepted' would be great from your side.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. While converting FAT => NTFS [is possible](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307881) under Windows, converting the other way around is not. As a general rule, changing the file system means formatting your drive and loosing all your data. There is no way around this. In fact, that's [precisely what *formatting* means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_formatting) (edited for brevity):

> Disk formatting is the process of preparing a [...] hard disk drive for initial use. In some cases, **the formatting operation may also create one or more new file systems.** [...] The third part of the process, usually termed "high-level formatting" most often **refers to the process of generating a new file system.**

So, changing a file system is formatting and formatting deletes your data. Now, it is actually possible to restore the data lost when formatting a drive. In general, when a drive is formatted, the data is not actually overwritten. It will still be stored on the hard drive but in a way that is not accessible without the use of special tools. This is really not something you want to do unless you have formatted by mistake and need to recover your data.

If your objective is to change the filesystem of one of your drives, you should just copy all your data somewhere else, then format, and then copy the data back. You can use `mkdosfs` as [suggested by Dhaval Simaria](https://askubuntu.com/a/602989/85695) to create the new file system.

Finally, you should note that there is very rarely, if ever, a reason to use FAT32 today. NTFS is better in pretty much all ways.

Comment: But i am not abl;e to mount NTFS file System...
i Tryied with following command :

Comment: mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb

Comment: is there any other command ?

Comment: @vaibhav `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb` should be enough. However, I just read that you're using a 2.6 kernel. Is that true? If so, that changes everything, NTFS support was not very good back then. Please upgrade your system.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely need to backup your data, either to other partition on the disk or to an external hard drive as mentioned by @karel.

The package you need to install in your Linux PC to be able to format disk using FAT32 file system is:

***dosfstools***

```
 apt-get install dosfstools
```

Now that you have the tools installed, it is time to use it, so to format the drive using FAT32.
First check the partition you need to convert using:

```
 fdisk -l
```

You will see something like */dev/sda1, */dev/sda2, etc. Select the drive which you wish to convert.
Now lets format it with:

```
 mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/sdc1
```

*WARNING:Make sure you BACK-UP your data. Be really careful before formating a disk, you will not be able to recover your data, double check that you are applying the command to the right device before you hit ENTER.*

Comment: i am using linux based device. i have to copied some text files which is in that device to usb.

Comment: through that device m not able to connect NTFS file system USB drive.

Comment: The device has linux OS of version 2.6

Comment: try using 'Disk Utility' to check if it sees the usb drive.

Answer (score -2):

You will see something like */dev/sda1, */dev/sda2, etc. Select the drive which you wish to convert. Now lets format it with:

mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/sdc1

Where is the command to "select the drive you wish to format"